# Isolated scope on button click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am newbie to angularjs. Working on the directives in angularjs I have followed the example of a book AngularJS directive. From that i tried some of the samples but i am stuck with one of the example something of similar which i need to implement in my application.

The code is :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="directiveapp">

    <!--  Two way binding -->
    <div ng-init="title = 'Hello World'; subtitle = 'I am an app'">
       <h2 id="appTitle">{{title}}</h2>
       <h3 id="appSub">{{subtitle}}</h3>
       <button id="newAppTitle" ng-click="setAppTitle('App 2.0')">Upgrade me!</button>
        <div my-scoped-directive msd-title="I'm a directive, within the app{{title}}" msd-subtitle="subtitle">
          <h4 id="directiveTitle">{{title}}</h4>
          <button id="newDirTitle" ng-click="setDirectiveTitle('bob')">Bobit!</button>
          <button id="newDirSub" ng-click="setDirectiveSubtitle('Time to submerge')">Empty the ballasts!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End of directiveApp -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('directiveapp', []);

app.directive('myScopedDirective', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope : {
        'title' : '@msdTitle',
        'subtitle' : '=msdSubtitle'
      },
    link : function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    console.log($scope)
    $scope.setDirectiveTitle = function (title) {
       $scope.title = title;
    };

    $scope.setDirectiveSubtitle = function (subtitle) {
        $scope.subtitle = subtitle;
    };
  }
 };
});
```

The problem is when i am clicking on the buttons No click events is firing. the texts are not getting changed. 
On clicking the Bobit button the text should changed from Hello world to I'm a
directive, within the app Hello World

Here i am attaching the plunker link : http://plnkr.co/edit/NdnWDqr9XCph6uNvJwlc?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct way to do it since the directive applied on a element is compiles as a directive but inside that element does not have scope of your directive it contains the scope of your controller.
**app.js**

```
  var app = angular.module('directiveapp', []);

    app.directive('myScopedDirective', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'EA',
          scope : {
            'title' : '@msdTitle',
            'subtitle' : '=msdSubtitle'
          },
          templateUrl:'main.html',
        link : function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        console.log($scope)
        $scope.setDirectiveTitle = function (title) {
           $scope.title = title;
        };

        $scope.setDirectiveSubtitle = function (subtitle) {
            $scope.subtitle = subtitle;
        };
      }
     };
    });
```

check out updated plunkr [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/kFG1c9yN6xP3zDjMwAFr?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

With the ng-click you calls a function in a controller.

put this:

```
$scope.setDirectiveTitle = function (title) {
   $scope.title = title;
};

$scope.setDirectiveSubtitle = function (subtitle) {
    $scope.subtitle = subtitle;
};
```

inside the parent controller or modify your directive to have his own controller

```
app.directive('myScopedDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope : {
      'title' : '@msdTitle',
      'subtitle' : '=msdSubtitle'
    },
    template: '<h4 id="directiveTitle">{{title}}</h4>' +
      '<button id="newDirTitle" ng-click="setDirectiveTitle(\'bob\')">Bobit!</button>'+
      '<button id="newDirSub" ng-click="setDirectiveSubtitle(\'Time to submerge\')">Empty the ballasts!</button>',

    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.setDirectiveTitle = function (title) {
        $scope.title = title;
      };

      $scope.setDirectiveSubtitle = function (subtitle) {
        $scope.subtitle = subtitle;
      };
    }
  };
});
```